# Convert PHP-Date in Javascript-Date

Tags: javascript, php, date

With this PHP-code I get the first day of the actual month

```
date('Y, n, 1')
```

The output ist

```
2014, 4, 1
```

How can I convert it to the Javascript-Date because the Javascript-Date, especially the month is zerobased. That means the output 2014, 4, 1 will be the 1st may 2014.

Comment: You just need to subtract one from the month.  What are you wanting to do: create a js variable from a PHP date?  Or just get a js variable which is the first day of the current month?  Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $month = date("n");
    $year = date("Y");
    $day = 1;
?>
var myDate=new Date("<?php echo $month?> <?php echo $day?>, <?php echo $year?>");
alert(myDate);
```

May be this help. <kbd>JS Date Demo</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks you gave me an important hint. My solution is now `function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month -1, day).getTime();
  }`